# Filter format for URL list-based policies in Edge

Tags: url, download, microsoft-edge, policy

I want to allow to download .msg - Files without warning on the Edge-Browser.

I know already the way how to do it thanks to the documentation of microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#disable-download-file-type-extension-based-warnings-for-specified-file-types-on-domains

My Problem is that i have following URL to download the msg-File:

blob:https://custom.domain.com/123456

Now i tried several pattern like:

Working:

{"domains": ["blob://*"], "file_extension": "msg"}

Failing:

{"domains": ["blob:https://custom.domain.com/"], "file_extension": "msg"}

{"domains": ["custom.domain.com"], "file_extension": "msg"}

My goal is that i can specify the host in the pattern.
Otherwise all "Blob msg-Files" will be allowed.

Comment: From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmmore-url-list-filter%20format#additional-filter-information), we can know that `blob` and `https` are both standard schemas. But it seems that we can only use one schema in the pattern. You can also have a try with `blob://custom.domain.com` to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately i tried "blob://custom.domain.com" aswell.
I guess there is no way at this moment with two standard schemas like you said.

Comment: Have you tried `{"domains": ["blob://[*.]custom.domain.com"], "file_extension": "msg"}` ?  Or if `custom` is the only host you want to allow: `{"domains": ["blob://.custom.domain.com"], "file_extension": "msg"}`. The point is to delete the `http` part, I think.